# TIC TAC TOE for two human players, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I was trying to do code for two human payers tic tac toe game, but I am getting an error. I had successfully made one computer and one human but got stuck in this one. if anyone can help me find the error would be great.

```
def drawBoard(board):
# This function prints out the board that it was passed.
# "board" is a list of 10 strings representing the board (ignore index 0)
    
    print(' ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2] + ' | ' + board[3])
    
    print('---+---+---')
    
    print(' ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5] + ' | ' + board[6])
    
    print('---+---+---')
    
    print(' ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8] + ' | ' + board[9])
    

def inputPlayerLetter():
# Lets the player type which letter they want to be.
# Returns a list with the player’s letter as the first item, and the computer's letter as the second.
    letter = ''
    while not (letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
        print('Do you want to be X or O?')
        letter = input().upper()
# the first element in the list is the player’s letter, the second is the computer's letter.
    if letter == 'X':
        return ['X', 'O']
    else:
        return ['O', 'X']


def whoGoesFirst():
# Randomly choose the player who goes first.
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return 'player2'
    else:
        return 'player1'


# This function returns True if the player wants to play again, otherwise it returns False.
def playAgain():
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')



def makeMove(board, letter, move):
    board[move] = letter


# Given a board and a player’s letter, this function returns True if that player has won.
# We use bo instead of board and le instead of letter so we don’t have to type as much.
def isWinner(bo, le):
    return ((bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le and bo[3] == le) or # across the top
    (bo[4] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[6] == le) or # across the middle
    (bo[7] == le and bo[8] == le and bo[9] == le) or # across the bottom
    (bo[1] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[7] == le) or # down the left side
    (bo[2] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[8] == le) or # down the middle
    (bo[3] == le and bo[6] == le and bo[9] == le) or # down the right side
    (bo[1] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[9] == le) or # diagonal
    (bo[3] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[7] == le)) # diagonal

# Make a duplicate of the board list and return it the duplicate.
def getBoardCopy(board):
    dupeBoard = []
    for i in board:
        dupeBoard.append(i)
    return dupeBoard


# Return true if the passed move is free on the passed board.
def isSpaceFree(board, move):
    return board[move] == ' '



# Let the player type in their move.
def getPlayer1Move(board):
    move = ' '
    while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board, int(move)):
        print('What is your next move? (1-9)')
        move = input()
    return int(move)


def getPlayer2Move(board):
    move = ' '
    while move not in '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'.split() or not isSpaceFree(board, int(move)):
        print('What is your next move? (1-9)')
        move = input()
    return int(move)

# Returns a valid move from the passed list on the passed board.
# Returns None if there is no valid move.




# Given a board and the computer's letter, determine where to move and return that move.
def getPlayer2Move(board, player2Letter):
    if player2Letter == 'X':
        player1Letter = 'O'
    else:
        player1Letter = 'X'

# Here is our algorithm for our Tic Tac Toe AI:
# First, check if we can win in the next move


print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')



# Reset the board
while True:
    theBoard = [' '] * 10
    player1Letter, player2Letter = inputPlayerLetter()
    turn = whoGoesFirst()
    print('The ' + turn + ' will go first.')
    gameIsPlaying = True


# Player’s turn.  
    while gameIsPlaying:
        if turn == 'player1':
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            move = getPlayer1Move(theBoard)
            makeMove(theBoard, player1Letter, move)


            if isWinner(theBoard, player1Letter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('Hooray! You have won the game!')
                gameIsPlaying = False

            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'player2'


        else:
            # Computer’s turn
            move = getplayer2Move(theBoard, player2Letter)
            makeMove(theBoard, player2Letter, move)

            if isWinner(theBoard, player2Letter):
                drawBoard(theBoard)
                print('The computer has beaten you! You lose.')
                gameIsPlaying = False
            else:
                if isBoardFull(theBoard):
                    drawBoard(theBoard)
                    print('The game is a tie!')
                    break
                else:
                    turn = 'player1'


    if not playAgain():
       break
```

I have tried human and computer but want to do this, so not sure what code I am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the problem? You have an error? You have some problems in your code, like typo in getPlayer2Move and isBoardFull undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your functions seem kind of ok. To make it work:

- Did -1 to all your numbers, python lists start with 0 index.
- I renamed the getPlayer1Move() to getPlayerMove() and deleted getPlayer2Move(), since it is the same function for both players.
- Defined isBoardFull().
- Modified your while block code.

So here the result:

```
import random

def drawBoard(board):
    # This function prints out the board that it was passed.
    # "board" is a list of 10 strings representing the board (ignore index 0)
    print(' ' + board[0] + ' | ' + board[1] + ' | ' + board[2])
    print('---+---+---')
    print(' ' + board[3] + ' | ' + board[4] + ' | ' + board[5])
    print('---+---+---')
    print(' ' + board[6] + ' | ' + board[7] + ' | ' + board[8])


def inputPlayerLetter():
    # Lets the player type which letter they want to be.
    # Returns a list with the player’s letter as the first item, and the computer's letter as the second.
    letter = ''
    while not (letter == 'X' or letter == 'O'):
        print('Do you want to be X or O?')
        letter = input().upper()
    # the first element in the list is the player’s letter, the second is the computer's letter.
    if letter == 'X':
        return ['X', 'O']
    return ['O', 'X']


def whoGoesFirst():
    # Randomly choose the player who goes first.
    if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
        return 'player2'
    return 'player1'


# This function returns True if the player wants to play again, otherwise it returns False.
def playAgain():
    print('Do you want to play again? (yes or no)')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')


def makeMove(board, letter, move):
    board[move-1] = letter


# Given a board and a player’s letter, this function returns True if that player has won.
# We use bo instead of board and le instead of letter so we don’t have to type as much.
def isWinner(bo, le):
    return ((bo[0] == le and bo[1] == le and bo[2] == le) or # across the top
      (bo[3] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[5] == le) or # across the middle
      (bo[6] == le and bo[7] == le and bo[8] == le) or # across the bottom
      (bo[0] == le and bo[3] == le and bo[6] == le) or # down the left side
      (bo[1] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[7] == le) or # down the middle
      (bo[2] == le and bo[5] == le and bo[8] == le) or # down the right side
      (bo[0] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[8] == le) or # diagonal
      (bo[2] == le and bo[4] == le and bo[6] == le)) # diagonal


# Return true if the passed move is free on the passed board.
def isSpaceFree(board, move):
    return board[move-1] == ' '


# Let the player type in their move.
def getPlayerMove(board, player):
    move = 0
    while move not in range(1, 10) or not isSpaceFree(board, move):
        print(f'What is your next move {player}? (1-9)')
        move = int(input())
    return move


def isBoardFull(board):
    return not any([x == ' ' for x in board])


# Here is our algorithm for our Tic Tac Toe AI:
# First, check if we can win in the next move
print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')
# Reset the board
while True:
    theBoard = [' '] * 9
    player1Letter, player2Letter = inputPlayerLetter()
    turn = whoGoesFirst()
    print('The ' + turn + ' will go first.')
    gameIsPlaying = True

    # Player’s turn.
    while gameIsPlaying:
        # Player's move
        if turn == "player1":
            letter = player1Letter
        else:
            letter = player2Letter
        drawBoard(theBoard)
        move = getPlayerMove(theBoard, turn)
        makeMove(theBoard, letter, move)

        # Check if the game is over
        if isWinner(theBoard, letter):
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            print('Hooray! You have won the game!')
            gameIsPlaying = False
        elif isBoardFull(theBoard):
            drawBoard(theBoard)
            print('The game is a tie!')
            gameIsPlaying = False

        # Change player's turn
        if turn == "player1":
            turn = "player2"
        else:
            turn = "player1"
    if not playAgain():
        print("Goodbye!")
        break
```

Comment: It works now, but it won't tell who's turn is next just the same prompt 'what is your next move.'

Comment: @ankurlakhanpal There you go, you only needed to give the player to getPlayerMove and put it in the text.

Comment: @ankurlakhanpal if you could accept my answer would be cool though